# Best practice for "Watch key changes" in etcd v3

Tags: etcd, etcd3, etcdctl

we want to use etcd with the "watch" function to change our "/etc/hosts" file.
A node should change the value and the watch should then write the change in "/etc/hosts".

Node1 Input:

```
etcdctl put master-server "192.168.10.1 master-server.int.server.io"
```

Node2 Watch:

```
etcdctl watch master-server | head -3 | tail -1 | tee  >> hosts.file
```

Node2 Output:

```
192.168.10.1 master-server.int.server.io
```

This works fine but now i want a output with multiple lines like this:
Node 2 Output:

```
192.168.10.1 master-server.int.server.io
192.168.10.2 slave1-server.int.server.io
192.168.10.3 slave2-server.int.server.io
```

My thought was:

```
etcdctl put master-server "192.168.10.1 master-server.int.server.io \n192.168.10.2 slave1-server.int.server.io \n192.168.10.3 slave2-server.int.server.io"
```

But it doesnt work.

The Output is:

```
192.168.10.1 master-server.int.server.io \n192.168.10.2 slave1-server.int.server.io \n192.168.10.3 slave2-server.int.server.io
```

Does anyone know the best way to handle my problem?
And how do I get multiple lines into a value?

Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following do what you want?

```
export ETCDCTL_API=3
echo -e "hello\nworld" | etcdctl put mykey
```

and to read it back:

```
etcdctl --write-out=json get mykey | jq .kvs[0].value | sed 's/"//g'  | base64 -d
```

Comment: @Silas If my answer does what you want, please consider accepting it. Thanks